# Using Mysql data stored in options from plugin Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a option page in my plugin and it is stored in table `wp-options`.

The option value is:

```
a:1:{s:9:"tablename";s:9:"Personeel";}
```

Now I just want to select `Personeel` from the option value, how do I accomplish this?

EDIT:

I have the following code now, but still doesn't work

```
mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax");
$sql1="SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name like 'fixformdata_options'";
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
$tablename = unserialize($result1);

$sql="SELECT * FROM ".$tablename[1]." WHERE personeelsNummer = '".$q."'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
```

Comment: [PHP unserialize](http://au2.php.net/unserialize) and [how to extract data from a post meta serialized array](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18463/how-to-extract-data-from-a-post-meta-serialized-array)

Comment: change your sql to $sql="SELECT * FROM ".$tablename[1]." WHERE personeelsNummer = '".$q."'";

Comment: stijn, I have updated my answer, you can replace your code with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use [***`maybe_unserialize()`***](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize) function of wordpress.

```
$myoption =  get_option( 'fixformdata_options' );
$myoptionValue = maybe_unserialize( $myoption );    

$sql="SELECT * FROM ".$myoptionValue['tablename']." WHERE personeelsNummer = '".$q."'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is serialized data (wordpress uses `serialize()` to store data)

Suppose your variable is `$option` 
then 
your code will be

```
$option2 = unserialize($option) ; 
$option2[1] ; // here is your Personeel
```

Refer [***`unserialize`***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) on official documentation site for further reference

Comment: Ok now I have following code but it won't work anymore, i suspect there is something wrong with the sql statement


$sql="SELECT * FROM " + $tablename[1] + " WHERE personeelsNummer = '".$q."'";